# How to install a package not found in Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: 10.10, repository, package-management

I would like to install a package but don't find it in Synaptic Package Manager.

I was wondering how to find out the repository of the package and add it to Synaptic package manager so that I can find it and install it from there?

For example, this is the case when I am now looking for "djvused" under 10.10 Synaptic Package Manager

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`djvused` is included with the [djvulibre-bin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/djvulibre-bin) package. If you cannot find the program by it's package name, try the "package contents" option in the search box on the right side at [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). [Search for "djvused" in package contents](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=djvused).

If a program is relatively new, and no package exist in the Ubuntu repositories, you could try to find one using [PPAs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) (=Personal Package Archives).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes an application is installed part of a meta-package or with another name. This makes it hard to find from Synaptic. A good place to start searching is the [Packages Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/) archive where all packages provided are listed. Another source of information are the manpages for a given application (see [Manpage for Djvused](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/djvused.1.html)).